# what does '$' sign represent in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
STR1 DB "ENTER YOUR STRING : $"
STR2 DB "YOUR STRING IS : $"
INSTR1 DB 30 DUP("$")
```

Can someone tell me what does '$' sign mean in the above example? I know that DUP operator causes value to be repeated number of times. For example,

```
DELTA DB 212 DUP (?)
```

created an array of 212 uninitialized bytes. Similarly,

```
GAMMA DW 100 DUP (0)
```

sets up an array of 100 words, with each entry Initialized to O. But i am confused that would does the `INSTR1 DB 30 DUP("$")` mean?

Comment: The dollar signs mean the ASCII value for a dollar sign. They're part of the strings or duplication just like any character or value.

Comment: In DOS, the $ is the end of the string, IIRC, like ASCII 0 in C and newer Microsoft OSes.

Comment: `INSTR1 DB 30 DUP("$")` means the same thing as previous examples, ie. 30 times value of expression in parentheses. With x86 masm the `"$"` will be decoded as an ASCII character, which is byte value `36`. So it is equivalent to `INSTR1 DB 30 DUP(36)`, but the character `$` in source gives hint to the reader of source code, that purpose of that line is to pre-fill buffer with DOS-string terminator value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'$' marks end of ASCII stream in MS-DOS [int 21h call **AH = 09, print string**](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html); it's substitute in C would be ASCII zero.

Without more context, I would expect user input to be written over `INSTR1`, in which case the input (with length between 0 and 29 inclusive) would be automatically terminated by the dollar sign (and thus ready for printing with `int 21h`).